# Why is maximum level-of-detail capped at level 18 (1:4,252) when publishing web tile layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, tiles, arcgis-field-maps

I created a hillshade raster that I would like to use in the field with Field Maps on my phone. When I go to share this raster from ArcGIS Pro as a web tile layer, I'm having problems with the raster being capped at a relatively poor level-of-detail. As the screenshot shows, the highest the slider goes to is level 18 (1:4,252) for maximum resolution.

I cannot adjust the slider and I cannot change the tiling scheme from "Auto-suggest".

If I use Field Maps with this tile layer as the basemap, I run into the overzoom problem where the map disappears at a close enough zoom level. I've solved this in the past by adjusting values in the JSON data, but it doesn't solve the problem of not having the more-detailed tile layer, it just allows one to zoom into a pixelated lower-res version of their basemap.

**Is there a way to actually publish the tile layer at a level of detail that matches what I see in ArcGIS Pro?** I included the second screenshot to show the level of detail that I can see at 1:1000. Still pretty good. I've seen ESRI support documents that say other tiling schemes go up to 24 levels-of-detail, but I can't change my tiling scheme for whatever reason.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1, AGOL, and Field Maps.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, [this issue pertains directly to the coordinate system the map is projected on](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/sharing/overview/configure-web-tile-layer.htm).

Esri is typically using WGS 1984 Web Mercator, which is the default for ArcGIS online. [According to Esri, the level of detail is automatically calculated based primarily on your target coordinate system](https://tile%20scheme%20with). You are using a localized NAD1983 2011 projection, which I also am.

I found that with the local NAD1983 2011 projection, I cannot gain greater detail than 18 - 1:4106. I also tested using more compressed imagery rasters, and even just not having the imagery file at all; this does not make a difference. However, if you use the NAD1983 UTM Zone projection of your state, then the permitted detail can down up to level 18 - 1:1126.

However, if you use the WGS1984 Web Mercator projection, you can get detail up to level 23, as Esri advertises. I was unable to find a solution, but I hope this clarifies the issue.